# What are direct key signatures (0x1F) usages other than for revocation?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

While looking what the PGP Global Directory is, I have found that it's key has two strange signatures:

```
pub  2048R/CA57AD7C 2004-12-06            
sig dirct  4DD19F10 2014-01-21 __________ __________ []
sig dirct  0C2F4392 2014-03-15 __________ __________ []
     Fingerprint=50BB 6FFC 9719 DFD2 BEBB  04C6 9710 B89B CA57 AD7C 

uid PGP Global Directory Verification Key
...
```

(from [Ubuntu keyserver](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=vindex&fingerprint=on&search=0x9710B89BCA57AD7C))

Looks like they are direct key signatures (type `0x1F` from [RFC, section 5.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.1)), and as far as I understand, there is no point in them other than self-signature or revocation, but signatures above are neither of them. So, is there any other use case that makes sense, or are the signatures above someone's mistake?